# Path Drawing with different colors

Tags: ios, dictionary, mkmapview

I am working on physical activity application which automatically detects your activity motion  which is either driving or walking. I have map in my application and I have adopted following apple provided code, [breadcrumb](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/Breadcrumb/Introduction/Intro.html) to trace user walking and driving path.

When user walks, then drawing should be green; when user drives, then drawing should be red.

However since I am using one single mapviewcontroller and whenever user activity changes then it changes previous color as well. I could not able to get two different colors anyway. Only either all green or red.

Any ideas?

Comment: Good question, actually I had the same problem before. I would like to know the answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

you have to implement following method of `<MKMapViewDelegate>` and create **Bool flag** for your color

```
- (MKOverlayView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForOverlay:(id<MKOverlay>)overlay {
    if ([overlay isKindOfClass:MKPolyline.class]) {

        MKPolylineView *lineView = [[MKPolylineView alloc] initWithOverlay:overlay];
        if (flag == YES) {
            lineView.strokeColor = [UIColor greenColor];
            flag = NO;
        }
        else {
            lineView.strokeColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
        }
        lineView.lineWidth = 5.0f;

        return lineView;
    } 

    return nil;
}
```